# where to get tutorial explaining the mobile phone architecture?

Tags: mobile, mobile-phones

Has anyone got any idea where one can get a tutorial or books on the architecture of a Nokia mobile phone or any other mobile phone using an ARM microprocessor?

Comment: A tutorial explaining what? How to create a CPU?

Answer (score 0):

Look for ARM development boards and the documentation and tools that go with them.